# How do I use generic record in avro (java) with an actual array

Tags: java, arrays, avro

The avro type "array" uses the following code inside GenericDatumWriter

```java
  protected long getArraySize(Object array) {
    return ((Collection) array).size();
  }
```

So I've got a real array (quite a big array of primitive floats). 
I made the naive assumption that an avro array would at least permit storage of arrays, but from the above, it's clear, it's assumed to be a collection.
I really don't want to go around wrapping every element of my array of float so what can I do? I've tried searching for solutions but unfortunately the use of the word "array" for the generic type means I get swamped by false leads.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question - one way to do it is to convert the float array to bytes array (or more accurately, bytebuffer) using the "bytes" data type in the schema.
From my writer

```scala
    val bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(value.length * 4)
    value.indices.foreach { i => bb.putFloat(value(i))}
    bb.rewind()
```

and the reader

```scala
    case bb: ByteBuffer =>
      val flts = bb.asFloatBuffer()
      val lim = flts.limit()
      val out = Array.ofDim[Float](lim)
      0.until(lim).foreach( i => out(i) = flts.get(i))
      out
    }
```

Note, I couldn't figure a way to avoid the copies in each case - asFloatBuffer does not permit subsequent .array on the FloatBuffer